# Is Google Dataflow retrying DoFns when RuntimeException appears?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We have a simple pipeline, where we transforming data from Unbounded data source.

In one step, when we enrich the data from the external service, sometimes RuntimeException is thrown ( it's because Dataflow is so fast ( :p ) and the external services are not aware of this particular data ). After 10s it will be aware, and RuntimeException will not be thrown.

In this in mind we switched completely from using `failsafe` and we try to rely on native Dataflow mechanism ( according to this: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/troubleshooting-your-pipeline#detecting-an-exception-in-worker-code )

But we've found out, that this is not really working. I mean, the bundle is not redelivered to DoFn, so that our sink does not have all the data that comes to our source.

Also, when running locally, this exception also quits the execution of the whole.

Is that a problem only with this particular type of exception (RuntimeException)? How to force Dataflow to reprocess bundle?

## update

The `DoFn` in which the exception appears:

```
@DoFn.ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    String txHash = c.element().getHash();
    try {
        LOG.info("TransformId: " + txHash);

        // here the RuntimeException is thrown
        throw new new RuntimeException

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception during processing id: " + txHash, e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

And logs:

```
2018-02-22 17:15:53.633 CET
Receiver: 00ff ( this is source, we are receiving id"
2018-02-22 17:15:53.634 CET
TransformId: 00ff ( beginning of the DoFn )
2018-02-22 17:15:53.634 CET
getTxRest invoked: 00ff ( the enriching service )
2018-02-22 17:15:53.638 CET
Exception during processing id: 00ff
2018-02-22 17:15:53.834 CET
Uncaught exception: ( and here are the details that the log name is: "xxx/logs dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fworker"  )
```

Why am I saying that this is not retried? Because this id `00ff` does not exists in the log elsewhere.

Comment: Please include some code and elaborate how you're inferring that the bundle is not being redelivered?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks. What does getHash() do - is it deterministic (is it possible that, when the same element is retried, getHash() returns a different value)?

Comment: Also: what source are you reading from? An incorrectly implemented unbounded source could cause this, in theory.

Comment: getHash is invoked on DTO-like object so it's idempotent. Regarding the source, it's pretty much the same as JmsIO from sdk sources. We have a topic, so only one Reader at the time (to not duplicating stuff).

Comment: In this case I'm almost 100% confident that the reason is incorrect implementation of the source. Most likely, e.g., it might be acking records immediately when they are received, rather than in finalizeCheckpoint(). So when the bundle is retried, it retries reading from the source, and the source doesn't give this record back again because it's already acked.

Comment: That could be it! I will try this when I come back to work. The problem is that our queue is not really supporting acks. It's like send-and-forget kind of source. In this case I should give up with Checkpoints? What's the approach with that kind of sources? It's basically a tcp socket with data coming in.

Comment: Try passing the data from the source through Reshuffle.viaRandomKey() - that will effectively temporarily materialize it so retries will concern only the processing but not the reading, at the expense of small performance overhead.

Comment: @jkff It works! Thank you! I will provide an answer here. What is interesting ( regarding this finalize thing ) is that the id from the question does not appear as "finalized" in the logs ( we log precisely which id were finalized ). What could be the reason of it?

Comment: Not sure, would need to see the code of your source to see. But glad reshuffle helped!

Comment: (I moved my comment to an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be 2 reasons:

- If `getHash()` is non-deterministic
- If you're reading from a custom `UnboundedSource` that does not provide at-least-once reads. E.g., the source might not support acking at all, or might be incorrectly acking records immediately when they are received, rather than in `finalizeCheckpoint()`.

The second is more likely in this case. When the bundle is retried, it retries reading from the source, and the source doesn't give this record back again.

If the source can not be fixed, as a workaround, you can pass the data from the source through `Reshuffle.viaRandomKey()` - that will effectively temporarily materialize it so retries will concern only the processing but not the reading, at the expense of small performance overhead.